# A triangle has its sides on the lines $x+2y-5=0, 2x-y-10=0$ and $2x+y+2=0$. Find the radius of the circle inscribed in the triangle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I already found the solution which is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dN6b.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN0Eq.jpg)

However, I am still quite confused on how we got this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgBVr.jpg)

Can someone please explain? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The image you are confused on uses the [distance from a point to line formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation).

Comment: @peterwhy Why is -x+2y-5/√1^2+2^2 negative though? also the denominator in 2x-y-10

Comment: The linked formula in Wikipedia is given in absolute sign. If one consider just the content inside the absolute sign, its sign is related to which side of the line $(x', y')$ is on.

Comment: Not sure I understand the solution, but I do think I see a way to solve it.  It helps that 2 of those lines are perpendicular.

Answer (score 1):

I would graph this, find the coordinates of the vertices, calculate the length of each side using the distance formula, then calculate the perimeter and semiperimeter $s$.  The area of the triangle is $sr_i$, where $r_i$ is the inradius.

Comment: Can I ask what the distance formula is?

Comment: @Scintilla [Distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions)

Comment: @Scintilla - for 2 points with coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, the distance formula calculates the distance between them which is the same as the length of the line segment connecting them.  $d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$  (It's the Pythagorean Theorem applied to a coordinate plane.)

Comment: Also, use Heron's formula to calculate the area of the triangle.